# Iterate through a URL to save an unknown number of pictures

Tags: python, url, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape multiple pictures from a peer-review website to carry out some image based analysis, and I'm having trouble trying to figure out if I can change the URL to scrape every picture from a particular paper. The full paper is here: https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/716043v1.full

The URL for the image I am using is: https://www.biorxiv.org/content/biorxiv/early/2019/07/26/716043/F1.large.jpg?width=800&height=600&carousel=1 . 'F1.large' refers to 'Figure 1', and there is a total of 6 figures. Is there a way I can increment 'F1' so that it will collect all the figures into separate jpg files? I would also like it to work for any number of figures, as not every paper will have 6, some will have more, others less.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import urllib.request

url = "https://www.biorxiv.org/content/biorxiv/early/2019/07/26/716043/F2.large.jpg?width=800&height=600&carousel=1"
picture = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "f2.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the tags that contain the images. Specifically the `<div>` tags with `class="fig-inline-img"`. You can grab the alt attribute to refer to the figure

**Code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request


url = 'https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/716043v1.full'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

images = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'fig-inline-img'})
for each in images:
    fig = '_'.join(each.find('img')['alt'].replace('.','').split())
    img_link = each.find('a')['href']
    picture = urllib.request.urlretrieve(img_link, "{fig}.jpg".format(fig=fig))
    print ('Saved: {fig}'.format(fig=fig))
```